# Using inner objects in Elastic search or not?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a specific recommendation why or why not to use inner objects in the mapping structure of Elastic search.

Should we use in the JSON (and thus also in the mapping and the query):

```
"author":{
    "id":"12345679",
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
 }
```

OR

```
"authorId":"12345679",
"authorFirstName":"John",
"authorLastName":"Doe"
```

I know we can use both, but are there any differences to be expected when analyzing, indexing, searching ?

All feedback welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, Inner Objects are flattened into the same Lucene document as their root object. This is in contrast to a **nested** mapping which are treated as related, but separate, documents in Lucene.  This matters when you have two different sub-objects with the same attribute name...

Say you had a book object with an Author and an Editor, each of which has a first name... With a sub object, a search of firstName:Bob AND lastName:Smith would return a book that had an author of Bob Jones and an editor of Joe Smith.  Using a nested type you wouldn't match either of those documents.

So to your point, flattening your document structure would work in most cases (it's what is done behind the scenes anyhow, so there's not much difference).  You just need to be aware that "nested" is also an option if you need more semantics -- i.e. search for smith in all lastName fields.